# How to Pass Contact Form User Email Instead of SMTP email in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

Am Using Mail function in Laravel
I have configured .env with smtp
While submitting contact us form i want to set contact form From Email

How can I get dynamic email from contact us form in email instead of default smtp email.

```
 Mail::send('email.enquiry', ['data'=>$data], function($message) use ($adminEmail,$customerEmail) {

          $message->to($adminEmail)->subject('Enquiry Email');
          $message->from($customerEmail,'Customer Enquiry');

});
```

[See image of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30GVh.png)

Comment: MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS,MAIL_FROM_NAME set these in .env file remove $message->from(XX)

Comment: vishal set these to null?

Comment: Hmmm I guess i got it wrong, I didn't understand your point

Comment: I want contact form email as from address instead of smtp email

Comment: I believe $customerEmail is email coming from contact form?

Comment: yes $customerEmail is email set from contact form . But receiving email from default email of smtp

Comment: This is strange nothing wrong with code i believe,I'm hope $customerEmail is not null, Just for testing purpose hardcode the from email like $message->from('example@yourdomain.com','Customer Enquiry') and try if still you are getting smtp email in from then declare $msg->from() first and then $msg->to()